# Get page feed without fan messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook graph API, I want to get a page feed.

My query gets the page feed but also gets the messages posted by the fans like on these pictures:

[image: My query]

[image: The message on the page's timeline]

What should I add to my query so I can only get the feed from the page itself without the fan posts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy – use `/page_id/posts` instead of `…/feed`.

Could have figured this out easily yourself btw. by looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections

Comment: Only thought of the feed. Thanks!